# Как ограничить подсказки SuggestView только городами России

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Совпадения по улице, району и прочее - не нужны.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете задать приоритетную область поиска через [опцию `boundedBy`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/SuggestView-docpage/?from=SO#SuggestView__param-options.boundedBy) или программно дописывать к запросу страну: `"Россия, "+<запрос пользователя>`